# Why double square brackets don't work in if statement with grep?

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep, and-operator

Can somebody explain why this bash script doesn't work when the if statement is in double square brackets, while without any brackets it does?

```
if [[ echo "word1word2" | grep -Eiq 'word1|word2' && echo "word3" | grep -Eiq 'word3' ]]
then
  echo "proceed"
else
  echo "don't proceed"
fi
```

Comment: `[[` is a command, not grouping syntax. The expressions inside `[[ ... ]]` aren't arbitrary shell pipelines.

Comment: What goes inside `[[ ]]` is a *conditional expression* not a command. `ls -lt foo` will run the `ls` command with the arguments "-lt" and "foo", while `[[ ls -lt foo ]]` will check whether the value of the variable `$ls` is numerically less than ("lt") the value of the variable `$foo`. These are completely different things.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need test operator at all:

```
if echo "word1word2" | grep -Eiq 'word1|word2' &&
   echo "word3" | grep -Eiq 'word3'
then
  echo "proceed"
else
  echo "don't proceed"
fi
```

It use *boolean logic*

If you want to use `[[`, then:

```
if [[ $(echo "word1word2" | grep -Ei 'word1|word2') && $(echo "word3" | grep -Ei 'word3') ]]
then
  echo "proceed"
else
  echo "don't proceed"
fi
```

Comment: Yes I know they're not necessary, but I'm looking for an aswer why it's not working with double square brackets, because I wan't to learn the behavior.

Comment: Added a way to use `[[`